# What happens to {{ STATIC_URL }} in deployment

Tags: django, deployment, static

Simple question:

What happens to `{{ STATIC_URL }}` variable in deployment?. For example, if I'm using a filter like this:

```
@register.filter
def new_filter(g):
    from myapp import settings
    STATIC_URL = settings.STATIC_URL
    return STATIC_URL + 'dir/' + g
```

Am I going to have problems or Django will still point to the same `STATIC_URL` as it is in localhost?.

I have read the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#deploying-static-files-in-a-nutshell) but I'm still not sure about this.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your filter will always point to whatever is defined in `settings.STATIC_URL` - end of story.

If you change the settings for production, your filter will now point to your new `STATIC_URL`. If you don't, it wont.

If your `STATIC_URL` is a relative URL, your URLs will automatically resolve to the host.

- `/static/` on development might be looked up as localhost/static/
- `/static/` on production example.com the browser will attempt example.com/static/

If it's absolute, then well production or development the browser will read the same resource until you change `STATIC_URL`.

Comment: Oh, great. Then everything will remain the same. When using collectstatic do I need to change my filter to tell it about STATIC_ROOT?.

Comment: @RobertSmith, `STATIC_ROOT` has nothing to do with your filter. It simply sets where static files are collected. It would be up to your web server to map your `STATIC_URL` to your `STATIC_ROOT` (e.g. apache serving the directory `/path-to-my-static-root/` from `/static/`)